# Invoke JavaScript in thread loop

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, multithreading

i am using

> `this.webbrowser.InvokeScript("JS function", arguments);`

to call a javascript function ==> works fine
but i need to use Threading System for Multi tasking

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

how can i call a javascript function in a thread loop??

my project is to create a GCS for UAV (Ground control station for drones), so i have geographical coordinate coming from my drone (GPS), 
and i need to draw the path in my windows app.

so i'm loading a localpage code (using google api,html and javascript) in  a web browser, 
this is the JS function i need to call (not to use it in my windows app, just to execute the function in my browser):

> ```
> function DrawLinePlane(lat,lon,alt){      // some code
>       flightString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lat,lon,alt); // Add LineString points.
>           //some code
>     }
> ```

so basically when ever i receive new coodinate i have to call the DrawLinePlane finction in my page,
for this i'm using a thread loop to receive those coordinate and draw that path, and the invokeScript didn't work in this loop

Comment: What do you mean by the the invokeScript didn't work in this loop? How did it not work?

Comment: js code executing in a browser if we do not mention of nodejs, so it's impossible to execute you client side code into server side code.

Comment: @AlexFilatov this looks like it might be a web browser component inside a winform. The question might be how to execute code in the event thread of the application vs the js thread of the webbrowser control.

Comment: Look for BeginInvoke

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something like this in your thread:

```
webbrowser.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.webbrowser.InvokeScript("JS F", arg)));
```

Comment: "WebBrowser doesn't contain a definition for invoke" 
I'm having this error

Comment: It contain, see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx. Can you post your code?

Comment: Got you now, you are using System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser and not System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser, so in this case must do it as follows: webbrowser.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.webbrowser.InvokeScript("JS F", "s"))); Updated my answer as well.